# Send value of button not working [Angular Material Bootstrap]

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hey I try to send the value of button to a function like this

```js
<button #mybtn value="somthing" (click)="filterTable(mybtn.value)" mat-stroked-button>mybtn</button>
```

and in my ts components:

```js
  filterTable(filterValue) {
    console.log(filterValue);
  }
```

It console Undefiend

but when i make my button without the Bootstrap like this

```js
<button #mybtn value="Somthing" (click)="filterTable(mybtn.value)">mytn</button>
```

This way is console "Somthing" and work.
why???

Comment: I assume you have the `import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';` imported in your e.g AppModule?

Comment: is imported in my appModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to access the value with:

```
  <button #mybtn="matButton" value="Test" (click)="filterTable(mybtn._getHostElement().value)" mat-stroked-button>Basic</button>
```

But that is rather a hack because we are using private API from Material. Why not directly pass the value into the filterTable call?

```
  <button #mybtn="matButton" (click)="filterTable('Test')" mat-stroked-button>Basic</button>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-81dzfr?file=app/button-types-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the native element to get the value.
Add this to your .ts file

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
...
export class SomeComponent {
@ViewChild('mybtn', {static: false}) mybtn: ElementRef;
...
public filterTable() {
   console.log(this.mybtn.nativeElement.value)
}
```

Omit the parameter from your `logButton` method so it becomes just

```
(click)="filterTable()"
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button #mybtn value="somthing" (click)="filterTable(mybtn)" mat-stroked-button>mybtn</button>
```

and in your .ts

```js
filterTable(mybtn) {
    console.log(mybtn.value);
  }
something like this
```

Comment: still undefiend, but when i remove the bootstrap from the button it works

Answer (score -2):

Why your htlmElement doesn't have the class attribute ??
you can also add class with [ngClass]="'yourClass'"

Comment: I think you should write